# Splitting numbers in a list and outputting a specific number from it

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to use a list of 20 numbers all stored in the same cell and separated by spaces. Eg in `A1` I have:

> 0 0 1 1 2 3 4 7 8 9 10 12 14 16 18 21 24 28 32 37

The code below (that I have in `B1`) will show how many numbers (or words, anything separated by spaces) are in cell `A1`:

> =IF(LEN(TRIM(A1))=0,0,LEN(TRIM(A1))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))+1)

The output of `B1` is 20.

I want to be able to input a number between 1 and 20 in cell `A2` and have the output of `B2` be the number corresponding to the value at that position in `A1`. For example input 19 in `A2` would output 32 in `B2`.

I have several of these number sequences and as far as I can tell most of them can't be represented by a formula which would have been a lot easier. I could also put each number in a separate cell and use a large collection of IF() functions but that would be tedious with so many sequences.

I have tried SEARCH() with `A1` data and `B1` formula altered to:

```
1:0 2:0 3:1 4:1 5:2 6:3 7:4 8:7 9:8 10:9 11:10 12:12 13:14 14:16 15:18 16:21 17:24 18:28 19:32 20:37
```

> =SEARCH(A2&":",A1)

Now when inputting 19 into cell `A2` I get an output of 90 (the first character of the sequence being searched for is the 90th in the cell). I think this information might help me to output the number after the `:` which in this case is 32.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your edit, you could use the `90` you got in `MID()`.

```
=MID(MID(A1,SEARCH(A2&":",A1),SEARCH(A2+1&":",A1)-SEARCH(A2&":",A1)),FIND(":",MID(A1,SEARCH(A2&":",A1),SEARCH(A2+1&":",A1)-SEARCH(A2&":",A1)))+1,999)
```

The formula is a bit long, but would be shorter if you use another cell. For instance, if you put:

```
MID(A1,SEARCH(A2&":",A1),SEARCH(A2+1&":",A1)-SEARCH(A2&":",A1))
```

in C2, then the first formula will become

```
=MID(C2,FIND(":",C2)+1,len(C2))
```

Comment: The formula may be long, but its easy to repeat for a dozen or more sequences of numbers. Much more efficient than my fallback plan of dividing the numbers into multiple cells and then using 20 IF() functions for my output. Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

A couple of alternatives.

Copy A1 to C1 (because B1 might be in the way) then apply Text to Columns on C1 with Space as the delimiter. In B1:

```
=INDEX(C1:V1,A2)
```

or,

in B1 (or B2 if you prefer) enter  `=CHOOSE(A2,X)`
and in A3 enter `=SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",",")`

then replace `X` with the result of Copy and Paste Special Values on A3.